# Debugging maven tests with IntelliJ

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I've read multiple variants of this question (sorry for adding another), but none have offered a working solution.

I am trying to debug a failing test in the application thingsboard.  I can reproduce the problem at the command line with:

```
mvn test -Dlicense.skip=true -DfailIfNoTests=false -Dtest=MqttNoSqlTestSuite
```

When I change the "mvn" to "mvndebug", I see the following message at my terminal:

```
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8000
```

Inside IntelliJ, I click the debug button, and my IntelliJ console says:

```
Connected to the target VM, address: 'localhost:8000', transport: 'socket'
```

and the command line process starts running.

So far, so good.

The problem is that none of my breakpoints get hit, even ones attached to lines that print a message to the console, so I can be positive are being executed.

I have tried multiple variants of the command line, including just about every permutation of the following flags:

```
-DforkCount=0 -DreuseForks=false -DforkMode=never
```

I'm just stuck.  Any idea how I can get IntelliJ to halt the running code at a breakpoint?

Comment: IntelliJ don't think your sources correspond to the process being run.  Maybe you have an incorrect value for "Search sources using module's classpath" on the configuration panel for the Remote job?

Comment: Try it with this plugin https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7179-maven-helper - it uses all three flags: "-DforkCount=0 -DreuseForks=false -DforkedMode=never"

Comment: @Meo - I have tried using mavenhelper, with the exact same problem, except that all the output occurs within the IntelliJ console.

Comment: Works fine for me out of the box, with JUnit 4.9  - https://i.imgur.com/wEXfW6s.png  Try it in a new clean project.

Comment: it is `-DforkMode=never` not `forkedMode`, that's the problem... What did you do in the plugin that it did not work for you?

Comment: I've tried four things with the plugin, all producing the same results I described above.  1) Debug MqttServerSideRpcNoSqlIntegrationTest (which is the first item on the context menu when I'm in the class containing my test); 2) Debug: test;  3) Debug: validate; 4) Creating a new goal with the cmd line options listed above

Comment: @Thorbjørn - I've tried the default option for that setting (No Module), and also "application" which is the only other choice that makes sense.

Comment: The problem is probably in your project, try to make a minimal example and upload it...

Comment: Do you *need* to run the tests externally via mvndebug? Can you just run the tests from source, inside IntelliJ... ? (you have the source, right?)

Comment: @vikingsteve it is possible to screw your project so it does not work either way, with JUnit 5 - the test is probably not even running.

Comment: If you have the source you can always recompile and debug should work.

Comment: @vikingsteve - I could run the tests from inside the IDE.  I am doing it this way because it is the most transparent to me, but, as noted above, I have tried running them internally with mavenhelper with similar results.

Comment: @meo - I don't think the project is screwed up because I am trying to test only a small code modification from a fairly well-used repo (https://github.com/thingsboard/thingsboard), and if it were too broken, someone else would have noticed.

Comment: org.thingsboard.server.actors.DefaultActorServiceTest works just fine... who know what you are doing...

Comment: Could you clarify by "works just fine"?  You were able to set a breakpoint, run the test, and the debugger halted at the breakpoint?

Comment: of course, all that.

Comment: Ok, great.  How specifically did you run the tests?  Did you do any special configuration?

Comment: @Meo - I downloaded a new copy of the source, imported it as a new maven project, and still could not get it to work.  If you can tell me what you did, I might be able to reproduce your success.

Comment: downloaded, opened as maven project, `install -DskipTests` because I do not have their database, added breakpoint to DefaultActorServiceTest#before, `right click | Debug Maven | Debug DefaultActorServiceTest`.   What is your Maven version?

Comment: @Meo - Does the test pass when there is no breakpoint set?

Comment: Yes. BTW, AFAIK when you debug with maven, you have to make sure to `install` other changed modules, or the breakpoint won't catch at the right place. It is just better to run it normally as JUnit by IntelliJ, not by Maven.

Comment: @Meo - Something must be jacked on my end; the only way I can get the tests to pass (fresh copy of the code, with or without breakpoints) is to run them externally using mvndebug.  When I run them internally (either directly or with maven helper), some server the tests need isn't being instantiated, and they fail.

Answer (score 0):

for me once you put in command line -Dmaven.surefire.debug i go in top menu, run => attach to process, then i choose my process with the good port and all goes well.